# Memory of a Void pointer

Tags: c, pointers

This is kind of a very basic question. I just wanted to know what will be in the memory of a void type of pointer.

Any help is really appriciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A `void` pointer is just a value which provides an address in memory. What is actually pointed to by a `void` pointer cannot be determined without further information.

As to what is in the memory occupied by the `void` pointer, it will be a 32 bit value on a 32 bit architecture and 64 bit value on a 64-bit architecture (and so on.)

Interpretation of this value is very much dependent on the underlying architecture and how it implements memory addressing.

Comment: Good point @SteveJessop, I've updated the answer accordingly.

Comment: "What is actually pointed to by a `void` pointer" cannot be determined *at all*, since `void` doesn't have any values. However, one might cast a `void` pointer to, say, `unsigned char` in order to determine the content at this specific memory address. Note that having the content of a memory address does not imply having a value.

Comment: Well, if you know it's a `struct` then you know the memory pointed to is a `struct`. Hence why I said 'without further information'. With further information it's perfectly possible to know what is pointed to!

Answer (score 0):

a pointer is a memory address, so it will be the same whether it's a void pointer or an Object's pointer...

Answer (score 0):

`void` is a type that has no values.

Accordingly, if you have a `void *foo`, C won't allow you to read `*foo`, let alone assigning some value to it.

Hence the answer to your question is: you can't find out the value of what is pointed to by a `void` pointer. You have to cast the void pointer to some other type, and the value at the address pointed to by the new pointer is interpreted according to its type.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, it also a pointer, so the size should be equal to ordinary pointer.